# WebPack configuration failed

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

I've some problems with configuration file on webpack.

Right now I've this structure: [the stucture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M4ujd.png)

package.json looks like this:

```
{
  "name": "webpack-4-tutorial",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "dev": "webpack --mode development ./src/index.js --output ./dist/main.js",
    "build": "webpack --mode production ./src/index.js --output ./dist/main.js"
  },
  "author": "Andrii Hordynsky",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.5",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "webpack": "^4.16.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.1.0"
  }
}
```

Index.js is just : `console.log("hello, booooiiii");`

When I'm running 'npm run build' it works and shows this outcome: 
[outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LlAm9.png)

I'm adding babel with: "`npm install babel-core babel-loader babel-preset-env --save-dev` and it works as well too: [babel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UJCqD.png)

Adding .babelrc file :

```
{
"presets": [
   "env"
   ]
}
```

And start to create webpack.config.js with this structure as well:

```
// Webpack v4
const path = require('path');
module.exports = {
  entry: { main: './src/index.js' },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'main.js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

and delete

```
"dev": "webpack --mode development ./src/index.js --output ./dist/main.js",
    "build": "webpack --mode production ./src/index.js --output ./dist/main.js"
```

from 'scripts' at package.json

[deleting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i9Y2f.png)

Now I have this structure:
[newStructure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zBm4v.png)

And, when I run `npm run build` I'm expecting some small .js file in `/dist/main.js`, but I received the stack of an errors [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gogVW.png)

When I delete "script" from `package.json` errors still here...
[new Errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5XmJF.png)

Sorry if there is some bad English or text as well, just, the head is completely boiling...

Comment: Also, sorry if it's kind of silly question, but hope you will take in count that I'm new in this community and really doing my best to learn some new things in the web.

Comment: Write to webpack.config.js this{

module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
};

}

Seems like it works

Comment: a) Screenshots and off-site resources are not a good idea to be adding to the question. The question needs to be self-contained. b) if you just deleted the 2 lines you said you would be left with a dangling comma  after `exit 1",`

Comment: @apokryfos is right, when you deleted the `scripts` properties you got an invalid `package.json`: you would be left with a dangling comma after `exit 1",`


Why would you want to delete your `scripts`?


If you delete `scripts` from `package.json` you can not run `npm run build` anymore since there isn't a script with that name. 


You should probably adjust your `build` script to 
``` "build": "webpack --config webpack.config.js" ```
and add ```"mode": "development"``` to your `webpack.config.js`

Comment: Thank you @bamse , watch this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=deyxI-6C2u4 . 

It kind of help too :)

Comment: Thanks!

How did you solve your issue?

Comment: Hi, @bamse, to be honest, it's solving really easy. 
I didn't understand the work principles of Webpack 4 .

to run your app with webpack you need have in "scripts" (at package.json) some properties like :build/dev etc, it looks like this in my code: http://prntscr.com/kap2iv

Answer (score -1):

you have forgotten to add '.env' file,if you have just cloned the project, your gitignore rules does not allow to track '.env' file.